# Visual basic If and else not working 2015

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, if-statement

I am a newbie and I am facing some problem with the 'if' and 'else' function of visual basic.
I have added a button labeled as Save, its code is as given below:

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        Dim savedata7 As New System.IO.StreamWriter("dat0C.bin")
        savedata7.WriteLine("checked")
        savedata7.Close()
    End If
    If CheckBox1.Checked = False Then
        Dim savedata7 As New System.IO.StreamWriter("dat0C.bin")
        savedata7.WriteLine("unchecked")
        savedata7.Close()
    End If
    If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
        Dim savedata8 As New System.IO.StreamWriter("dat1C.bin")
        savedata8.WriteLine("checked")
        savedata8.Close()
    End If
    If CheckBox2.Checked = False Then
        Dim savedata8 As New System.IO.StreamWriter("dat1C.bin")
        savedata8.WriteLine("unchecked")
        savedata8.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

And another button labeled Load, its code is given below:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Try
        Dim dataloader As New System.IO.StreamReader("dat0C.bin")
        Label17.Text = dataloader.ReadToEnd
        dataloader.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    Try
        Dim dataloader As New System.IO.StreamReader("dat1C.bin")
        label10.Text = dataloader.ReadToEnd
        dataloader.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try 
If Label17.Text = "checked" Then
        CheckBox1.Checked = True
    Else
        CheckBox1.Checked = False
    End If

    If Label10.Text = "checked" Then
        CheckBox2.Checked = True
    Else
        CheckBox1.Checked = False
    End If
End Sub
```

The Save button(Button5) is working perfectly fine, but the Load button(Button1) is not working as it should, on clicking Button1 the files 'dat0C.bin' and 'dat1c.bin' are loaded in 'Label17' and 'Label10' respectively but it is not working(i.e. it is not Checking the CheckBoxes1 or 2) from

```
If Label17.Text = "checked" Then
    CheckBox1.Checked = True
Else
    CheckBox1.Checked = False
End If

If Label10.Text = "checked" Then
    CheckBox2.Checked = True
Else
    CheckBox1.Checked = False
End If
```

Please correct me, If I'm doing anything wrong in it.

Comment: You should name your controls.

Comment: Visual Studio comes with a powerful debugger; using it you would not only learn about how code *really* executes, but likely figure this out much faster than we can decipher what you are up to.  That said, those empty Catch blocks are eating any errors your code is encountering.  Dont do that

Comment: Try a message box instead of giving the text to labels to see what the program is actually reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because in the reading code you use ReadToEnd instead of ReadLine.
This method reads back the newline character added by WriteLine and doesn't strip it away as ReadLine

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Try
     Using dataloader = New System.IO.StreamReader("dat0C.bin")
         Label17.Text = dataloader.ReadLine()
     End Using
Catch ex As Exception
     MessageBox.Show("Exception=" & ex.Message)    
End Try
....
```

A part from this you really should put the creation of disposable objects like the reader and the write inside a using statement to be sure that these objects are properly closed and disposed ALSO in case of exceptions.

Said that, your code could be simplified a lot if you use the static methods of the File class

WRITING

```
File.WriteAllText("dat0C.bin", If(CheckBox1.Checked, "checked", "unchecked"))
File.WriteAllText("dat1C.bin", If(CheckBox2.Checked, "checked", "unchecked"))
```

READING

```
Label17.Text = File.ReadAllText("dat0C.bin")
Label10.Text = File.ReadAllText("dat1C.bin")
CheckBox1.Checked = (Label17.Text = "checked")
CheckBox2.Checked = (Label10.Text = "checked")
```

Answer (score 1):

Asside from not naming your controls, and not disposing properly of your `StreamReader` or `StreamWriter` instances the reason this is not working correctly is because when you write your file you call `WriteLine` - which appends a carriage return and line feed onto the end of what you've written.

You then read the file, and put the content in a label, which itself will render the CR/LF albeit not visible to you. You then compare to the `Text` of this label but without the CR/LF - so that comparison evaluates false.